# Find out if a ruby script is currently running

Tags: ruby, grep, find

I have a ruby script that gets triggered every minute by a CRON job called 'process_files.rb'.

process_files.rb executes another ruby script called 'process_client.rb' with paramaters like so:

```
ruby process_client.rb -c ABC -s 123 -f /path/to/client/file/client_file
```

Since process_files.rb runs every minute I want to avoid running process_client.rb if a version of it is currently running with same -c parameter. So if process_client.rb is currently running for -c ABC, it will not 
execute the ruby command above.

Both of the scripts are in the same directory called /cdir.

This is what I've got in process_files.rb but it is not working:

```
client = "ABC"
name = "process_client.rb -c #{client}"
needle = `find /cdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name #{name}`.to_i
if needle > 0
   puts "DONT RUN the ruby script for client abc"
else
   puts "RUN the ruby script for client abc"
   ruby process_client.rb -c ABC -s 123 -f /path/to/client/file/client_file
end
```

Then before I execute process.files.rb I execute process_client.rb for client ABC, which has some code to put it into sleep mode for 30 seconds, like so:

```
...some code
sleep 30
...some code
```

The problem is that process_files.rb never finds the current execution of process_client.rb for client ABC and executes another version when it should not.

Something is probably wrong with the `find` command but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Ruby script to run everything.

You can have your Ruby script launch your `process_files.rb` and `process_client.rb` using `Process.spawn` you can get the process PID to know if they are running or not.

Obivously you will need to modify the code below to suit your needs, but this should get you started.

```
def process_client(client)
  client_pid = Process.spawn('/usr/bin/ruby', 'process_client.rb', '-c', client)
  Process.detach(client_pid)
  client_pid
end

def process_files(some_arg)
  # do some stuff
end

process_client_pid = process_client('ABC')

loop do
  begin
    Process.getpgid(process_client_pid)
    # This means the process_client.rb script is running
  rescue Errno::ESRCH
    # Code here for when the client is not being processed
    process_client_pid = process_client('ABC')
    process_files(some_arg)

  sleep 30
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but consolodating the 2 scripts into 1 isn't an option for me.

Comment: This wouldn't consolidate 2 into 1, this would be a 3rd script to launch the other 2.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  I gave a basic example of the problem I was having without providing details of the entire system flow.  Your solution would work if the process were a stand alone process, it will not work in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using the wrong strategy to detect a match from `find`. It will return a list of filespecs (possibly empty) separated by new lines. Calling `to_i` on that list doesn't make sense. You could instead pipe it to word count to get the number of lines, and convert *that* to an int:

```
`find ... | wc -l`.to_i
```

Also, in the line that assigns a value to `name`, did you mean to use backticks rather than double quotes?

Comment: Thanks for the response . I did add the wc -l to the end of the find. I'm still not finding process_client.rb

Comment: Would you address my question at the end referring to `name`? This could be a problem too.

Comment: I intended to use double quotes. When I used bacticks the name variable wasn't recognized in the find command

Comment: That's a very odd file naming scheme. So the file name includes spaces? If that's the case, then you should `require shellwords` and call `Shellwords.escape()` on `name`.

Comment: that -c #{client_name} is an argument passed into the ruby script.  So i'll probably be removing that from 'name', but I'll still have to figure out how to find a version of process_client.rb that is running that is using the same {client_name} value.

Comment: So your solution of adding wc -l to the find command works if I remove the arguments from the name variable.  I'm half way there but am skeptical that find can compare arguments passed into process.

Comment: What do you mean "passed into process"?  Also, why not use Ruby's file finding mechanism? If you know the file name, all you need is `File.file?(filespec)`.

Comment: Why can you not have the Ruby process started once on system startup and have _it_ be responsible to do the process only once per client? Seems like your approach is adding unnecessary complexity. Am I wrong?

Comment: By "Passed into process" I meant arguments passed into process_client.rb.  process_client.rb is passed in arguments, like -c client_name. find and Ruby's file finding mechanism will find another version of process_client.rb that is running, but I need to go deeper than that.  I need to compare the arguments, (-c client_name), as well.

Comment: Making the ruby process responsible for only processing once per client is not an option.  process_files.rb reads files in from a queue which may contain files from the same client one right after another.

Comment: `find` will only find file names and directories in the file system. It does not have access to any runtime arguments. (This makes a lot of sense, since that would be outside the scope of the `find` utility, an there could be multiple simultaneous invocations of a given file.)